# Asynctask doesnt work after too many rows retrieved

Tags: java, android, mysqli, android-asynctask

I am doing an app where I synchronize my online DB to the offline DB everytime the user logs in. The table is dropped in offline, recreated then new rows gets added ( Its neccessary to drop it and add new instead of just checking and adding the rows that are not in the table already). I had about 200 rows in my online table and they are synchronised to my offline table relatively fast (in the background, then I tried 3000 and it was still processing. But When I generated 90 000 rows and tried to synchronize it to my offline DB it wouldnt move.

The log in onPreExecute() executed, but none of the logs in my doInBackground. json is not null.
For each retrieved row I am adding a row in offline.

Anyone know what could be the issue?
I tried adding LIMIT 200 in my PHP Scripts and still didnt do it, which was weird, cause when I had 200 rows it executed, but when I limit the output to 200 it does not. 
Thank you for any answers, that would bring me closer to the solution.

```
public class SyncVykresToOffline {

    String DataParseUrl = "/scriptsforandroidapplicationofflinemode/SyncVykresToOffline.php";
    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    DBHelper dbh;
    private Context mContext;
    public static boolean syncedvykres = false;
   int k = 200;

    public SyncVykresToOffline(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        dbh = new DBHelper(mContext);
    }


    public class SyncVykres extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;


        public SyncVykres(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.i("Poradie_zacal","ano");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {




            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost(DataParseUrl);


            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", String.valueOf(k)));
            try {
                myConnection.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                HttpResponse response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int i = 0;
            try{

               int vykres_version;

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("Poradie_json",String.valueOf(jArray.length()));

                String
                        Nazov_vykresu;


                int Version,
                        ID_vykres,
                        ID_stav,
                        ID_zakazka,
                        Poradie;

                if(json == null) {
                    Log.i("Poradie","son is null");
                }


                while(json != null) {
                    Log.i("Poradie","been here");
                    ID_vykres = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("ID_vykres"));
                    vykres_version = dbh.getVykresVersion(ID_vykres);
                    Nazov_vykresu = json.getString("Nazov_vykresu");
                    ID_stav = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("ID_stav"));

                    ID_zakazka = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("ID_zakazka"));
                    Version = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("Version"));
                    Poradie = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("Poradie"));
                    Log.i("Poradie",json.getString("Poradie"));

                    dbh.SyncVykresToOffline(new technicky_vykres(ID_vykres,Nazov_vykresu,ID_stav,ID_zakazka,Version,Poradie));

                    i++;
                    json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                }



            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            syncedvykres = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: added Logcat logs.

```
06-25 20:36:07.013 8278-8308/com.example.chris.normitapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
        at com.example.chris.normitapplication.offline.SyncVykresToOffline$SyncVykres.doInBackground(SyncVykresToOffline.java:102)
        at com.example.chris.normitapplication.offline.SyncVykresToOffline$SyncVykres.doInBackground(SyncVykresToOffline.java:44)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Edit 2: added PHP Script from where the JSON array is retrieved from:

```
<?php

include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");


$vykres = array();



$sql = "SELECT * FROM `technicky_vykres`";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));



while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}


echo json_encode($emparray);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Issue identified when logging STR:

```
<html>
    <head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
    <hr><center>openresty</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you show your logCat? There might be a stack trace that was printed or more space is allocated due to the magnitude of the method.

Comment: @Nordii which filter? Vebose? Debug? Warn? Error? Assert? Info?

Comment: verbose should be fine

Comment: @Nordii added the logcat to OP, not sure what are we looking at, I filtered by the name of the Activity that is called.

Comment: At line 111 some sort of conversion is being attempted where the types are not correct, like getting a String instead of array or the wrong input. If your code worked for smaller sizes, that raises more questions as to why it doesn't work. Is it possible that there is an error somewhere in this 90,000 row database? I hope not, for your sake.

Comment: Yeah its strange, well the rows are generated, only AI ID and rest are set to NULL, when I generate 400 by the same method it still shows, when I generate alot more it no longer works. I had the same problem in my web application, I was using clientside for datatatables, it worked for small amount of rows but stopped working after 5k+, so I had to switch to serverSide, but here its serverside already.

Comment: Can you identify what line SyncVykresToOffline.java:102 is? Since it's the one throwing the error, it's likely to help start figuring out why your JSON is erroring.

Comment: @BryanDormaier Line 102 is `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);` where str is `str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()`

Comment: Have you compared your outputs to make sure your JSONArray response from the server has the same form? It erroring there to me says that maybe there's a difference in your JSON response and there may be some initial parsing that needs to change slightly.

Is it possible that outputting all your rows in JSON gives just an array where as setting a limit sets the array as an arg inside a return object so it can also return offset and limit, etc?

Comment: I added a response that shows the internal code of the JSONArray throwing your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon realizing that the PHP script stopped working because too many rows & columns were retrieved instead of * I only Selected data that I truly needed (about 1/3 of all columns), then I added a where clause where ID would be above the number I sent from post and I keep repeating the script until finally the response is not "null".

Thank you for everyone who contributed to finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is, its the data that is breaking the loop and causing your program to end without going through the complete data set. I just added simple try/catch (see below) to printout any data objects, that we can't parse and but still continue to process the next row. Of course you'll need to have better error handling in place for production quality code.

```
     while(json != null) {
                try{
                Log.i("Poradie","been here");
                ID_vykres = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("ID_vykres"));
                vykres_version = dbh.getVykresVersion(ID_vykres);
                Nazov_vykresu = json.getString("Nazov_vykresu");
                ID_stav = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("ID_stav"));

                ID_zakazka = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("ID_zakazka"));
                Version = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("Version"));
                Poradie = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("Poradie"));
                Log.i("Poradie",json.getString("Poradie"));

                dbh.SyncVykresToOffline(new technicky_vykres(ID_vykres,Nazov_vykresu,ID_stav,ID_zakazka,Version,Poradie));

                i++;
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    //Something wrong with the data? log it and see if you can find the culprit row/data....
                    Log.i("The faulty jason obj: " + json);
                    continue; //Move on the next one....
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I tried your code, but nothing gets caught at all.

Comment: Did the program run through the full set 90k? or stopped in the middle? If so, do you see anything on the logcat? exception/stacktrace?

Comment: yeah, check OP, I logged the response but and got error 50 - bad gateway. But no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `JSONArray` believes your response is not formed as a Json Array.

Here's the code within `JSONArray` throwing your error:

```
    public JSONArray(JSONTokener readFrom) throws JSONException {
    /*
     * Getting the parser to populate this could get tricky. Instead, just
     * parse to temporary JSONArray and then steal the data from that.
     */
    Object object = readFrom.nextValue();
    if (object instanceof JSONArray) {
        values = ((JSONArray) object).values;
    } else {
        throw JSON.typeMismatch(object, "JSONArray");
    }
}
```

So the tokener does not recognize the object as a `JSONArray`. I would take a look at your raw response and see if adding a limit doesn't change the response to be an object with a result array inside of it (so that it can also include arguments to help web calls handle paging). Either way, there's something in the format of the response that the tokener does not recognize as being a Json array.

Comment: Hello, thank your for for taking the time to look it up. It should be returning the same data, I had the LIMIT there only slightly for testing, but now I have it back in its original form (getting ALL rows from the table). The only comparison I am doing as you can see is logging one of the variables while json != null.  I also tried logging the length of the jArray but nothing gets logged (null?) but when logging a string in the `if(json == null)` the string is not logged so json is not null, nor any exceptions are caught.

Comment: Added my serverside PHP if it can somehow provide additional information. Edit: Added log of my str. Seems like the error is 502 bad gateway. How could that be fixed in my case?

Comment: Nothing is logged because you're throwing an error earlier and exiting out of your try throw catch before you get to any logs .

Try either logging your string before trying to construct an array out of it, or catching your debug on line 102 and examining your string. The error remains the same. Something in your string is causing the tokener to not recognize it as an array.

Comment: Ah just saw your second comment, hold on.

Comment: I realised that when I directly put the link to my browser I get the same error. Meaning the problem is not my android code but the script iself.

Comment: Ok, if you're getting a 502 error, then yeah, everything else is going to fail, because the response is not an array.

Something is going wrong on your request.

Comment: hmm so its the PHP script then. I am going to try and modify it to output the response in a different way.